# Corresponding Perl DBIx::Class for SQL LIKE AND NOT LIKE STATEMENT

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I am just a newbie to Perl and I am trying to use Perl DBIx::Class ORM. I want to convert a SQL statement which is sometime like

```
SELECT `COLUMN_1` FROM TABLE 
    WHERE `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE "regex1" 
    AND `COLUMN_NAME` NOT LIKE` "regex2".
```

I know of `search_where` statement to add conditions but I am not able to find equivalent of LIKE and NOT LIKE ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad about the incomplete information it's DBIx::Class

Answer (score 3):

[`search_like`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#search_like) is just a convenient shortcut. You probably do not want to use that.

There are several ways to achieve this with `search` though. Remember that [ResultSet](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet) calls with [`search`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#search) can be chained, to build up the final ResultSet.

```
$rs->search(
    {
        column_name => { -like => 'foo' },
    }
)->search(
    {
        column_name => { -not_like => 'bar' },
    }
);
```

Alternatively, you can also just combine them, as shown [in this older mailing list post](http://lists.scsys.co.uk/pipermail/dbix-class/2013-March/011165.html).

```
$rs->search( 
    { 
        column_name => { 
            -like     => 'foo', 
            -not_like => 'bar', 
        } 
    }
);
```

Or you can chain them with an `AND`, which is more verbose.

```
$rs->search(
    {
        -and => [
            { column_name => { -like     => 'foo' } },
            { column_name => { -not_like => 'bar' } },
        ]
    }
);
```

All of these do the same thing.

---

You can find additional information about this syntax in [SQL::Abstract](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Abstract), which is used by DBIx::Class under the hood.

Note that `LIKE` does **not** take a regular expression.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help , BTW is there any work around for the regex , since in the SQL LIKE statement I am using a string regex 
Thanks

Comment: @Always_Beginner which database engine are you using? `LIKE` should not actually support regex. Some DBs have a `REGEXP` operator for that.